# C# Visual Studio any way to replace => with normal syntax

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio generates a getter/setter shortcut syntax for C# e.g.
{ get => m_display_name; set => m_display_name = value; }
Is there any shortcut to switch it to the normal getter/setter syntax
I don't like the => syntax, it's not easy to modify and put a breakpoint on the setter.

Comment: This begs the obvious question: Why not use auto-properties?

Comment: What snippets do you have that setup properties like that? Are you using a 3rd party plugin?  Also is this when implementing interfaces and abstract classes or when you use refactoring to inject the properties that do not exist? More context around how you generate these getter/setters will help.

Comment: You can use [quick actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2019#to-see-a-light-bulb-or-screwdriver) to do that, e.g. `Use block body for accessors`

Comment: Yeah but it still doesn't generate the body like that by default, not with `m_` prefix on member fields, not in a vanilla VS install. This smells like a linting or code style plugin

Comment: Just right click to add break point, if that's your only argument

Comment: Expression body definition for property is supported beginning with C# 7.0. So there is a direct way that change C# version to `C# 6`. As to how to change the version, refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#configure-multiple-projects).

Comment: English version of link from @Kyle Wang https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: @kapsiR - can I accept your quick actions as an anwser to this question?

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy Sure, I added it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [quick actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions?view=vs-2019#to-see-a-light-bulb-or-screwdriver) to do that, e.g. `Use block body for accessors`